# passing variable from php page to another php page generated using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php page(calendar.php) which is using javascript to load a php calendar(calendar_start.php) and display the calendar in the center of the page.

I am trying to obtain a variable on the calendar_start.php page, however I cannot access variable which I am able to access from the calendar.php page.

below is one of the scripts used on calendar.php to generate canendar_start.php:

```
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript">
function initialCalendar(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "calendar_start.php";
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    showmonth = month;
    showyear = year;
    var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

and below is part of the page calendar.php where I am generating the calendar:

```
<body onLoad="initialCalendar(<?php $_GET['page']; ?>);">
```

I am unable to grab the variable on calendar_start.php and I would really appreciate any help.

Kindest Regards,
Ryan

EDIT::

This may be helpful, this is the error when I am trying to display the variable on calendar_start.php

Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\wamp\www\project\calendar_start.php

Comment: Which one is the variable you're trying to grab?

Comment: $page, which is in the URL of calendar.php and I can grab in calendar.php using this:  $page = $_GET['page'];

Comment: You're sending a POST request, and trying to use GET on the PHP side? Try $_POST?

Comment: I've tried using $_POST and it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $_GET['page'] to $_REQUEST['page'].

$_REQUEST combines $_GET and $_POST together (with $_POST taking precedence). That way you won't have to worry about backward comaptibility if you change it in the future.

It is, however, a bad idea to echo ANY of these variable unsanitized to users browser.

EDIT:

Although your main problem is that you forgot the "echo" command in front of the variable.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using $_REQUEST however it does not work, I have also tried using echo and this wont work still.

Comment: Have you tried both? Try changing $_GET to $_POST or $_REQUEST *and* putting in echo.

Comment: I have, but can you please give an example to be sure I'm doing it right?

Comment: <?php echo (isset($_POST['page'])) ? $_POST['page'] : ''; ?>

Comment: Wait, can you post some code from calendar_start.php? How are you trying to use it?

Comment: at the moment I am just trying to display it, $page = $_GET['page']; I have also tried echo $page;      however when I can grab the variable I will be using it within mysql_query() to assign which calendar will be displayed

Comment: please help I'm really stuck

Comment: Where are you actually sending the variable as part of the AJAX request? I'd don't think you are even sending the variable to the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks JRL I've managed to solve it as from what you said I realised I wasnt doing that!